# Regex greedy range

Tags: regex, notepad++, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

`String to be matched = "AAA/up to eight upper case letters/AAA" : 
ex1 : AAA/BB/AAA
ex2 : AAA//AAA
ex3:  AAA/BBCCDDEEFF/AAA`

How can I match strings with zero to eight uppercase letters in the middle (i.e between the forward slashes) ?

I tried `regex : AAA/(?!(.*[a-z].*)[A-Z]{0,8})/AAA`

But it doesn't match any of above strings. 
(Regex `AAA/[A-Z]{0,8}/AAA` does match above strings, but It matches lower case letters too.
`ex: AAA/bb/AAA`)

Comment: Add Notepad++ tag, it is very important.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your original `AAA/[A-Z]{0,8}/AAA` was correct, but you've got "case insensitive" regex modifier set somewhere outside the regex so you match lowercase letters as well. (Did you check "Match case" check box in Notepad++?)

You may make the regex (or a part of expression) case sensitive with `(?-i)` construct:

```
(?-i)AAA\/[A-Z]{0,8}\/AAA
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/aS2iW8/1

Comment: Yes! that was the problem.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
^A{3}/([A-Z]{0,8})/A{3}$
```

Now the matched group `\1` would get you what's inside two `/`s.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fA6oV1/1)

Comment: hmm.. for some reason this matches strings like "AAA/bb/AAA" (at least in notepad++)

Comment: No this regex cann't match `AAA/bb/AAA`

Comment: @anubhava In some cases, it can. E.g. when the case insensitive mode is ON.

Comment: @anubhava, the OP seems to be using Notepad++ with case insensitive lookup enabled by default (effectively triggering the `/i` regex modifier).